# Delete deprecated code is bad or good idea?

Tags: java, architecture

In the previous version API, we created a module for creating a schedule in Webservice. Next week we'll release intermediate version product in production but we have one trouble. Customers said that they don't need this functional more. I'm a backend developer in this project, I refactored a few domain models and that saves this functional I must to refactored dto, view models and structure database. PM offers that I should use @Deprecated and save this part of code but I think that we should delete this part of code because in the next version API we have to write another module for creating schedules. I know that this part of the code will not be used in the next versions.

Comment: Yes, delete now.   Save it to the side (outside of the codebase), if you think the schedule creation functionality might be useful in the future and is nontrivial.  Postponing just creates technical debt.

Comment: I'm voting as _primarily opinion based_, but to still answer your question: I think flagging something as deprecated in an API is good if you know your API is already in use somewhere and it could break stuff if you delete parts. But if your scheduler isn't necessary at all and the project isn't used elsewhere, just remove it. I assume you're using version control, so you can always look back at your earlier scheduler code in the future if it somehow becomes relevant again. Leaving dead code in a project isn't something to recommend, as I've personally experienced with 10+ y.o. applications..

Comment: Why wouldn't you delete it? It's stored in version control if you ever need it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dead code needs to be found and removed; leaving dead code in is an obstacle to programmer understanding and action, and there’s the risk that the code is awakened which can cause significant problems. Deleting dead code is not a technical problem; it is a problem of mindset and culture, argued Kevlin Henney.

more:
https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/dead-code/